# We ...... some friends in for dinner

Tags: word-choice, tense

I came across a question and confused which is right one.

> We ...... some friends in for dinner tomorrow night.
>
> (A) have (B) are having  (C) do have (D) will have

In my opinion 4th one is preferred but answer is B option. I dont know the reason for it.

Comment: Sidenote - I'd get rid of "in" in that sentence.  Generally you say you'll have some people for dinner, or you'll have some people "over" for dinner, but not "in" for dinner.

Comment: Every single option is grammatical and possible. Which is *preferred* is entirely a matter of opinion.

Comment: @DavidRice  I would say the "in" is fine, although perhaps too advanced a nuance for English learners.  It implies something like "in town", as if the friends are traveling.

Comment: @Userthatisnotauser "You don't have friends for dinner ***tomorrow*** night, do you?" "Why, yes, we ***do*** have some friends for dinner tomorrow night."

Comment: It seems that more than one answer is correct. Maybe we are missing some context that supports a specific answer?

Answer (score 1):

Both B and D are possible ways of expressing future events.

Using the present continues with a future time phrase tends to be used for events that are following a plan, and indicate a high level of certainty about the plan. This is a good use of the present continuous meaning "in the future".

However, the meanings of "we are having friends for dinner" and "we will have friends for dinner" overlap. Both would be possible in this sentence.